# Can I dynamically configure Incoming Webhook for Microsoft Teams Channel?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, botframework, microsoft-teams

Is it possible to configure incoming connector or office365 connector using code instead of via MS teams website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you cannot configure the incoming web-hook dynamically/ Using code. This is by design. Could you please Raise a [user voice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public-preview/category/182881-developer-platform)?

Comment: Thanks @Nikitha. May I check if it is possible to use incoming webhook to send a reply to existing messages?

Comment: @chiaDev - Currently it's not possible to send a reply to existing messages using incoming webhook.